# YouTrack Workflows not Firing

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I have a basic scheduled workflow that creates issues, but can't get the flow to trigger as it should on the projects to which it is attached:

- I have 3 projects: A, B and C
- I have a scheduled workflow that creates a single issue (summary and description only) in **each of** A, B and C.
- When the workflow is attached to project B, it triggers and all 3 issues are created.
- When the workflow is attached to A and/or C, the workflow does not trigger.

Many of the project fields overlap, but given that I'm only setting the summary and description, i don't see that being a problem?

I can't find where workflow execution gets logged, so don't know if there are problems (but the flow does execute on project B)...?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an answer to the problem, this problem was resolved by upgrading from YT5 to YT6.

Part of the upgrade involved going through this problem: http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-1810 (resolved by backing up, uninstalling YT5, removing all YT folders, then installing YT and restoring backup)

That leads me to wonder if the problem wasn't related to a bad/locked/corrupted file somewhere in the YT directory?

Nevertheless, post upgrade, I attached the scheduled workflows as they were and they fired without hindrance.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that stateless and state machine rules are executed on behalf of a user who actually made changes that triggered a workflow. Scheduled rules, in turn, run on behalf of their author. Thus, make sure the author has respective permissions in all of the projects the rule is attached to.

Comment: Good point, thanks. All of the projects and rules were by the same user, and the user had admin rights too.